# Get an array of child posts IDs, wordpress 3.0, php

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

Ok here's one for ya...

On a custom template I'm using this code to retrieve & display a list of child pages/posts

```
$args = array(
                    'depth'        => 1,
                    'show_date'    => '',
                    'date_format'  =>     get_option('date_format'),
                    'child_of'     => $post->ID,
                    'exclude'      => '',
                    'include'      => '',
                    'title_li'     => '',
                    'echo'         => 1,
                    'authors'      => '',
                    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
                    'link_before'  => '',
                    'link_after'   => '',
                    'walker' => '' );

                    wp_list_pages( $args );
```

This works great, I'm also wondering how I can access/create an `array` of child post ID's. My goal is to access some `custom fields` meta data through the `get_post_meta()` function of each child post using it's ID.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I wasn't very clear with this one as it's the first time I've never recieved an answer from SO.

I managed to find the information I needed and will place it here for anyone else browsing with the same request.

ok - To get all child IDs..

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of=X');
    foreach($pages as $child) {

    // Now you have an object full of Children ID's that you can use for whatever
    // E.G 
    echo $child->ID . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: for posterity: using $pages as a variable name may cause errors as it is a global variable inside the Wordpress loop

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build an array of post ids for later use you can do this:

```
$pageids = array();
$pages = get_pages('child_of=X');
    foreach($pages as $page){
     $pageids[] = $page->ID;
}
```

And you have a clean array of just page ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
$children = get_posts('post_parent=SLUG_OF_PARENT_POST&post_status=publish');
foreach($children as $child)
{
echo '<br/>ID:'.$child->ID;
}
```

you can use other attributes (i.e. `$child->post_content`)...
if you need to define post_type, then add this argument too : `&post_type=POST_TYPE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```php
$my_page_id = 12345;

$child_query_args = array(
    'post_parent'         => $my_page_id,
    'post_type'           => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'      => -1,
    'fields'              => 'ids',
);

$child_query  = new WP_Query($child_query_args);

if ( $child_query && $child_query->have_posts() && $child_query->posts ) {  

    // (Since fields=ids, $child_query->posts is just an array of IDs)
    $child_ids = $child_query->posts;

    foreach ( $child_ids as $child_id ) {

        $whatever = get_post_meta( $child_id, 'whatever', true );

        echo esc_html($whatever);

    }

}
```